# How to expand/collapse row in Table visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, analytics, powerquery

I have 2 tables - IncidnetLog and IncidentLatest. IncidentLog is the list of logs for each incident , hence it contain multiple rows for same incident, containing duplicate value in Incident ID column. IncidentLatest is the latest and unique detail (latest row based on Modified date) from IncidentLog table.

I have created a report in Table visual in Power BI fetching IncidentLatest records. Now I have requirement to expand/collapse each row in the table visual which will show/hide the respective detail from IncidentLog table.

Is this possible in Table Visual? Or what can be alternate implementation for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can either use a matrix visual. If you put two fields on the rows it will automatically add a +/- button. If not then go to the matrix visual options under `Row Headers > +/- Icon` an activate it.

You can do this in a table visual as well (right click on the column value and chose `Group`). But I would recommend a matrix, its way easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

2023 now and I am still looking for a Table visual solution or improvement to both visuals.

Matrix visual works in this case but actually there are many limitations.
IF you have 3rd and 4th tables, Matrix visual does not fit very well.
If you have multiple row headers even turn off Stepped layout, some formatting like alternating row colors will not apply to Matrix row headers except the last layer.

Table visual solves the above problems but you lose collapse/expand, Rows subtotals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you chose the Table visual and the Table visual just has values. If you choose the Matrix visual, you will have rows and columns. The Matrix visual is one to the right from the visual you have selected in your screenshot.